# How many gates can I put on a 27 qubit quantum computer

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Recently I've been wondering how many gates I can put on a 27 qubit quantum computer, for example can I put like a million gates?

And also will that increase the time for the result to be calculated?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put one million gates on a 27 qubit quantum computer. The computation will be complete noise though, assuming you are using any noisy quantum computer. Also, for practical reasons (mainly time) I do not think you could actually even execute 1 million gates on a current quantum computer, regardless of whether it makes sense to do so. For example, on a IBMQ 27 qubit quantum computer the computation would decohere significantly after a gate depth of roughly 10-100.

Comment: Just to add, maximal depth depends on algorithm used. For example HHL algorithm shows decoherence very soon, while QAOA can be successfully run on current quantum computers.

Comment: that did answer my first question but I want to know if adding millions of gates will slow the culculation, [to be clear, I want to know if all the gates are culculating the result with infinite speed]